# PyQt change picture with keyboard button

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

this is my first post here and I haven't seen it anywhere so hopefully it is ok. I am trying to change the displayed image with a keyboard click (think slideshow). This is my code so far:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import os

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Document Analysis'
        self.left = 30
        self.top = 30
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.imagenumber=0
        self.initUI()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key=event.key()
        if key==Qt.Key_Right:
            self.imagenumber=self.imagenumber+1
            self.showimage(self.imagenumber)
            self.show()
        else:
            super(self).keyPressEvent(event)

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.showimage(0)
        self.show()

    def showimage(self,imagenumber):
        label = QLabel(self)
        directory = "C:\\Desktop\\Pictures"
        imagelist = os.listdir(directory)
        pixmap = QPixmap(directory + '\\' + imagelist[imagenumber])
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.resize(pixmap.width() + 500, pixmap.height())
        self.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It seems to be sort of getting somewhere, the first image displays just fine, and I know imagenumber does change, and when I stopped it from showing at first it resized the window but still didn't show the image. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

This is part of a larger project which is the reason for the extra space on the side of the picture, but help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close.  Try the following...

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import os

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Document Analysis'
        self.left = 30
        self.top = 30
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.imagenumber=0
        self.initUI()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key=event.key()
        if key==Qt.Key_Right:
            self.imagenumber=self.imagenumber+1
            self.showimage(self.imagenumber)
            # self.show()
        else:
            super(self).keyPressEvent(event)

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.showimage(0)
        self.show()

    def showimage(self,imagenumber):
        # label = QLabel(self)

        directory = "C:\\Desktop\\Pictures"
        imagelist = os.listdir(directory)
        pixmap = QPixmap(directory + '\\' + imagelist[imagenumber])

        # label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.resize(pixmap.width() + 500, pixmap.height())
        # self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Mainly, you need a persistent label.  You also only need to call show() once.